# Is orocos dead?

Tags: control, orocos

We are using orocos on the robot we have been developing for 3 years now and I have the feeling that Orocos is no longer maintained and the mailing lists are not only no longer active but also it is no longer possible to subscribe to them.

Do you have more information about the state of orocos? Is it a dead project?

Comment: i see some activity here ... https://github.com/orocos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The orocos software is available on github:

- https://github.com/orocos
- https://github.com/orocos-toolchain

Their KDL repo has been updated as recent as 2 days ago so I would say it's not dead. Try logging an issue using github to contact the developers instead of the mailing lists.